# How can I prepend an array value to the start of specific lines in a text file

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I want to prepend specific array values to the start of specific lines in a text file.

For example if I have an array `animals=(cat, dog, bird, lizard)` and a text file that looks like this:

```
.color
.age
.size
.breed
.name

.color
.age
.size

.color
.age
.size
.breed
```

How can I prepend cat to lines 1-5, dog to lines 6-8, bird to lines 9-13.
(each animal has a different number of sections)

The output text file should look like this:

```
cat.color
cat.age
cat.size
cat.breed
cat.name

dog.color
dog.age
dog.size

Bird.color
Bird.age
Bird.size
Bird.breed
```

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: why the dog lines are `6-11`? It looks 6-10.

Comment: How many empty lines are in the text file between the sections for each animal?

Comment: 1 empty line between each section. but theres also a different number of sections for each animal. I gave a bad example here. its not 5 sections for each animal, each animal can have a different number of sections from the text file.

Comment: Then it's _prepend cat to lines 1-5, dog to lines **7**-11, bird to lines 1**3**-17_, isn't it?

Comment: yea but the number of lines don't really matter. theyre flexible. for example i could have first 5 lines to cat, then next 10 to dog then the next 4 to bird. etc

Comment: What does really matter is that the posted information is consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like blank line is the separator so we can use that:

```
a=(cat dog bird lizard)
i=0 ac=${#a[@]}

while IFS= read -r line; do
   [[ $line =~ ^$ ]] && { ((i = (i + 1) % ac)); printf '\n';  continue; }
   printf '%s\n' "${a[i]}$line"
done < file
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can i prepend cat to lines 1-5 then dog to lines 6-…

We can also abuse `join` to join on a nonexistent field:

```
join --nocheck-order -j2 <(printf %s\\n ${animals[*]}) <(head -5 text)|tr -d ' '
```